# Python regex - Find and replace the second item of a pair

Tags: python, regex

I've been trying to do the following : Given a char like "i", find and replace the second of every pair of "i" (without overlapping).

```
"I am so irritated with regex. Seriously" -> "I am so rritated wth regex. Seriously".
```

I almost found a solution using positive lookbehind, but it's overlapping :(

Can anyone help me?

My best was this (I think) -> `"(?<=i).*?(i)"`

EDIT : My description is wrong. I am supposed to replace the SECOND item of a pair, so the result should've been: "I am so irrtated with regex. Serously"

Comment: So, what was your effort?

Comment: My best was this (I think) -> "(?<=i).*?(i)"

Comment: Still don't understand capture groups (can we replace stuff in capture groups...?) and the concept of "consuming chars".

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [regex](https://regex101.com/r/iZ0uH2/1) matches overlapped substrings because of the lookbehind `(?<=i)`. You need to use a consuming pattern for non-overlapping matches:

```
i([^i]*i)
```

Replace with `\1` backreference to the text captured with `([^i]*i)`.
See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bT9rB7/2).

The pattern matches:

- `i` -  a literal `i`, after matching it, the regex index advances to the *right* (the regex engine processes the string from left to right by default, in `re`, there is no other option), 1 char
- `([^i]*i)` - this is Group 1 matching 0+ characters other than `i` up to the first `i`. The whole captured value is inside `.group(1)`. After matching it, the regex index is after the second `i` matched and *consumed* with the whole pattern. Thus, no overlapping matches occur when the regex engine goes on to look for the remaining matches in the string.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/3TW6eF):

```
import re
pat = "i"
p = re.compile('{0}([^{0}]*{0})'.format(pat))
test_str = "I am so irritated with regex. Seriously"
result = re.sub(p, r"\1", test_str)
print(result)
```

Comment: @Robᵩ: Yes, but lazy matching is less efficient than character classes, and it requires a DOTALL modifier to match across lines.

Comment: What you meant after the literal "i" is that the regex index advances to the **right**, correct?

Comment: Sorry Wiktor, I stated the wrong issue. I've edited the question. The regex should be able to replace a second item, not a first.

Comment: And I just got it. It's (i[^i]*)i

Comment: No problem, readjust the grouping. `(i[^i]*)i`. I am ona mobile now, hence slow response.

Comment: I thought using the back reference \1 was the same as stating "Replace the captured group string". Actually now I think it's something like "Replace the matched string _after_ the referenced capture group".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110660/discussion-between-eduardo-almeida-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: It is easier to think of it so: match what you need to remove and match *and capture* what you need to keep and restore in the result with the backreference in the replacement pattern.

Comment: Ahhhhh, capture to restore in the result. That's great advice. Thanks a bunch (again)